# How to calculate distance between locations when one is changing user location and second one should be constant?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I have `IBAction`:

```
-(IBAction)pressStart{

locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

In

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        duration.text = @"00:00:00";
        speedLabel.text = @"00";
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    }
```

And this method:

```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    CLLocation *firstLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    location = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocationDistance meters = [location distanceFromLocation:firstLocation];

    NSLog(@"meters= %f", meters);
```

And I don't know why the `firstLocation` is changing. Maybe there is a way to capture firstLocation? This should be the location of the device when the button Start is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstLocation` in your code is not the first location since location updates started; it is the first location to be returned to you since the previous callback to the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method (the location services may collect multiple locations before calling back to your delegate method in certain circumstances -- the most recent location is always going to be the last object in the locations array).

If you need to store the first location since location updates started, you should create a property such as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *startingLocation;
```

Then in the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method, add the code:

```
if (!self.startingLocation) {
    self.startingLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

That will store the starting location into the property after the first callback. (You can set the property to nil if you want to reset it.)

Don't forget that the very first location you receive many not be very accurate, as it takes time for location services to get a fix on the device's position if they were not recently enabled.

Comment: @Ola Glad to hear! Please click the checkmark next to the above answer to 'Accept' it.

Comment: And I have a quick question about NSArray locations, cause it seems that the array have only one object, at index 0. Is it possible?

Comment: Clicked! :) I needed to wait 5minutes before I could click it, I don't know why

Comment: Yes, it's common for the array to have only one location in it. The only time it will have more than one location is when the system got a few location updates but for some reason wasn't able to immediately deliver them to your app. So, you'll get a callback eventually with all of these locations that you "missed" in the array. Realistically, you probably only need to call `[locations lastObject]` which gets you the most recent update...you probably will not have a need to look at any older location updates if they exist.

Comment: By the way, all of this is documented by Apple in their [API docs for CLLocationManagerDelegate here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW16).

Comment: Ok, now everything is clear, thank you one more time!